# NvM Config block always return NVM_REQ_NOT_OK

Tags: autosar

In my project NvM_Multi block and Config_block both are return the valus for NvRamErrorStatus_u8 as NVM_REQ_NOT_OK. While flashing the software there were no issues and the config block and multi block values are NVM_REQ_OK after few days of running the return value of the blocks are becomes NVM_REQ_NOT_OK. I have read AUTOSAR spec and understood config block value write as part of the write all before entering sleep and it will be stored, then the next wakeup cylce the config block shall return the value as NVM_REQ_OK. Here this is not happeneing and I presume block has been corrupted and is there any way to fix this issue. Luckily we found this issue during the long run test, if this issue is happening in field how this can be fixed? Could you guys please help.

Answer (score 1):

NvM is BSW component that depends on lower layer components, i.e. Fee.
You should check with a debugger if the error comes from NvM or from the SW component below it.
Config block is a system specific block and you must not modify it. You should create a new user block and provide a lower layer block for it, i.e. create also a new Fee block.

Comment: Here we are using External EEPROM and can we create a new block to store the compile config ID?